# Creating a rectangle with text inside a pattern

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new in HTML and CSS and there is a problem I am facing using CSS.

I want to create a section like this:

---Picture---

--Text--

---Picture---

--Text--

---Picture---

--Text--

---Picture---

--Text--

I want the text to be wrapped inside a rectangle with a specific background color. The issue is that whenever I am setting a background-color for my rectangle, the size of the div includes all of the content beneath.

```css
.lower-part {
  margin-top: 15%;
}
.lower-part .row .image img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}
.lower-part .row .textbox {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-part">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image"><img src="images/BadmintonPicture.svg" alt="Badminton Picture"></div>
    <div class="textbox1">
      Sports.
      <p>For me, nothing is better than regular excercise. It keeps me energetic throughout the day.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="image"><img src="images/CookingPicture.svg" alt="Cooking Picture"></div>
        <div class="textbox">
          Cooking.
          <p>I LOVE Food. I try to experiment with new recipes whenever I can. The Food Lab by Kenji Lopéz-Alt helps me being a better cook.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="image"><img src="images/ReadingPicture.svg" alt="Reading Picture"></div>
            <div class="textbox">
              Reading.
              <p> I love self-development books, because it helps me grow as a person.
                <span>Favourites:</span>
                <br>Slight Edge, Atomic Habits, How to Win Friends & Influence People .
              </p>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="image"><img src="images/GuitarPicture.svg" alt="Guitar Picture"></div>
                <div class="textbox">
                  Music.
                  <p>I grew up playing the violin but the guitar seemed way cooler. So I stick with that for the most part. Also, I like to sing every few minutes.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Sass

```
.lower-part {
  margin-top: 15%;
  .row {
    .image {
      img {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
      }
    }
    .textbox {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. I made you a snippet. It is using SASS so I compiled it for you. 2. You are not closing your divs so I voted to close this question as a typo-type question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<div>` tags.
It helps if you properly indent and use new lines for new tags, because this way you can easily keep track of open tags.

```
<div class="lower-part">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/BadmintonPicture.svg" alt="Badminton Picture">
        </div>
        <div class="textbox1">
            Sports.
            <p>
                For me, nothing is better than regular excercise.
                It keeps me energetic throughout the day.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

etc.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! I thought it must be a display issue. Turns out I am just dumb lol.

Comment: Please let us know if this solves your problem or if you have any further difficulty. Once the problem is solved, you can mark it as answered.

Comment: However since this a typo-type question, you could convert the answer to a comment and we could close and delete the question

Comment: I think it's an issue related to the bad practice of not formatting code neatly and it's good for programmers to be aware of that.

Comment: And how will bad formatters find this question and answer with a title of `Creating a rectangle with text inside a pattern`

Comment: because they will not be searching for "bad formatting", but issues such as this

Comment: Such as what? As I said, this question will not show in any search. "the size of the div includes all of the content beneath" is unlikely to be searched for